# Is the sample from a more limited subset than expected?

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test

I have a population of data points, each of which belongs to a group. For example, I have 1000 points split over 10 groups. But group membership is not equal, some groups are large while others are small.

I have taken a sample of 50 individuals from this population **and want to know whether the group representation in my sample is significantly different from that of a random sample**. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Perhaps you could use a chi-squared test. See the fairness of die example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test#Fairness_of_dice

Comment: This seems like the right approach, but then how would I weight that depending on the size of each group?